# Are inner classes commonly used in Java? Are they "bad"?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Are inner classes commonly used in Java?  Are these the same as nested classes?  Or have these been replaced in Java by something better?  I have a book on version 5 and it has an example using an inner class, but I thought I read somewere that inner classes were "bad."

I have no idea and was hoping for thoughts on it.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: "Terminology: Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes." -- From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487126/is-usage-of-anonymous-classes-in-java-considered-bad-style-or-good

Comment: (a) Yes (b) No (c) No unless you count lambdas & closures. If you can cite your source for the theory that they are 'bad' please cite it so we can avoid it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Inner classes are frequently used, and something very similar - anonymous classes - are practically indispensable, as they are the closest thing Java has to closures. So if you can't remember where you heard that inner classes are bad, try to forget about it!

Comment: just don't mention double-brace initializers...

Comment: closures are basically allowing a snippet of code to be shipped somewhere else, and still refer to its original surroundings.  It can be very, very nice.

Comment: @skaffman - ack! Just looked them up, couldn't quite believe it. You think you've created a List<int>? Guess again, my friend, guess again!

Comment: @DanielEarwicker Does Java have Anonymous Classes now?

Comment: @johnny Uh, since about 1997 I think! :)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker I should have said functions.

Comment: Ah, that's more recent, added in version 8 (2014), search for "lambda expressions" to find out more.

Answer (score 22):

They're not "bad" as such.

They can be subject to abuse (inner classes of inner classes, for example). As soon as my inner class spans more than a few lines, I prefer to extract it into its own class. It aids readability, and testing in some instances.

There's one gotcha which isn't immediately obvious, and worth remembering. Any non-`static` inner class will have an implicit reference to the surrounding outer class (an implicit 'this ' reference). This isn't normally an issue, but if you come to serialise the inner class (say, using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org)), you'll find that this can cause you unexpected grief.

Comment: if it's a concerns only to the class in question, then I'd say it messes readability if it's in a different file... In my case I'm thinking of using an non-public internal class to refactor a piece logic.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think they are evil or bad. Maybe they are not widely used, but they do have many uses,callbacks being one of them. A special advantage is that  they can extend from a different class than the outer class, so you could have multiple inheritance.

I would say that one of the issues with inner classes is that their syntax is somewhat "ugly". That's something that discourages some people. Here at work there are many of them.

Answer (score 2):

A good example of an inner class is the iterator implementation for a given collection type.  Its a class that implements a public interface, but has no business existing except in association with another class.  It allows you to model things that in C++ you would be forced to do with the friend operator.

Answer (score 2):

Non-static inner classes can hide a performance problem. They do have access to member fields on the enclosing class, but not directly, but via getters which are created automatically. This will be slower then just copying the members of the enclosing class to the inner class.

Some other problems with non-static inner classes are described [here](http://www.jroller.com/tomdz/entry/reflection_inner_classes)

Answer (score 1):

They are useful and can be very commonly used.  While you should be cautious about abusing the functionality, they aren't much more liable to be abused than any other language feature.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to remember is that you are going to trade flexibility for simplicity and cohesion by making the two classes more tightly coupled. You may want the classes to be tightly bound, but you are giving up the ability to transparently swap other classes into the place of what is currently your embedded class by not defining your class from an interface outside of the containing class.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example :

```
public class OuterClass {

private AnonymousInnerClass anonymousInnerClass = new AnonymousInnerClass() {
    @Override
    protected void printAboutme() {
        System.out.println("AnonymousInnerClass.printAboutMe.........");
        Class clazz = this.getClass();

        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {

            String message = Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) ? "public":(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())?"private":"protected");
            message = message + " " + field.getType().getSimpleName();
            message = message + " " + field.getName();

            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
};

public void displayAnonymousInnerClass() {
    anonymousInnerClass.printAboutme();
}

public void displayStaticInnerClass() {
    NestedStaticClass staticInnerClass = new NestedStaticClass();
    staticInnerClass.printAboutMe();
}

public void displayInnerClass() {
    InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass();
    innerClass.printAboutMe();
}

public void displayMethodInnerClass(){

    class MethodInnerClass {

        private String sampleField = "Method Inner Class";
        public void printAboutMe() {
            System.out.println("MethodInnerClass.printAboutMe.........");
            Class clazz = this.getClass();

            Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {

                String message = Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) ? "public":(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())?"private":"protected");
                message = message + " " + field.getType().getSimpleName();
                message = message + " " + field.getName();

                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
    }

    MethodInnerClass methodInnerClass = new MethodInnerClass();
    methodInnerClass.printAboutMe();
}

class InnerClass {
    private String sampleField = "Inner Class";
    public void printAboutMe() {
        System.out.println("InnerClass.printAboutMe.........");
        Class clazz = this.getClass();

        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {

            String message = Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) ? "public":(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())?"private":"protected");
            message = message + " " + field.getType().getSimpleName();
            message = message + " " + field.getName();

            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}


abstract class AnonymousInnerClass {
    protected String sampleField = "Anonymous Inner Class";
    protected abstract void printAboutme();
}

static class NestedStaticClass {
    private String sampleField = "NestedStaticClass";
    public void printAboutMe() {
        System.out.println("NestedStaticClass.printAboutMe.........");
        Class clazz = this.getClass();

        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {

            String message = Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) ? "public":(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())?"private":"protected");
            message = message + " " + field.getType().getSimpleName();
            message = message + " " + field.getName();

            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

in this example there is comparison  of every type of non static nested class with static nested class.Now if you run display method of Outer class for each nested class you will see output of each nested class printAboutMe() method,which has some reflection code to print all the member variables of nested classes.

You will see for non nested classes there is one extra  member variable other than declared variable string in code,which is only present at run time.

for instance if we execute following code for InnerClass. :-

```
public class NestedClassesDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();
    outerClass.displayInnerClass();
}
```

}

output is like this :-

```
InnerClass.printAboutMe.........
private String sampleField
protected OuterClass this$0
```

Note there is mystery member variable this$0 of type enclosing class(Outer class).

Now you are clear that inner classes keep reference to outer class.So image scenario where you pass reference of inner class to other outer world class and then reference never gets released to in turn OuterClass is also referenced , hence leak.

So this makes using inner classes bad if not used prpperly.

There not such case with static inner classes.Please run all display methods.Also if any problem in code please do point out.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a [contradiction in terms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), and 'non-static nested' can be replaced by 'inner'.