# What's this language feature called?

Tags: java

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        public void setBackground(Color c) {
           Logger.global.info("setBackground: c=" + c);
           super.setBackground(c);
        }
    };
```

I only know I can do `JPanel panel = new JPanel();`

Why can someone do the above? What's the name for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called an *anonymous class*.

That code basically creates a subclass of `JPanel` "on the fly" without giving it a name (thus the term *anonymous* class) and instantiates it.

**Related questions and links:**

- [Mindprod.com, Java Glossary: Anonymous classes](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/anonymousclasses.html)
- [Is usage of anonymous classes in Java considered bad style or good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487126/is-usage-of-anonymous-classes-in-java-considered-bad-style-or-good)

Comment: To be more exact anonymous inner class.

Comment: @AlexR, an anonymous class is *always* an inner class so "anonymous inner class" is kind of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It is an anonymous class that you extend and define additional methods or override existing ones.

Note that the same way you can extend interfaces or abstract classes.